# How to import Java List XML into C#

Tags: c#, java, xml, list, collections

I have a Java generated (List Collection) XML format of:

```
<java.util.Collections>
   <org.yccheok.jstock.engine.Stock> 
     <code> 
       <code> RBS.L</code> 
     </code> 
     <symbol> 
       <symbol> ROYAL BK SCOTL GR</symbol> 
     </symbol> 
     <name> ROYAL BK SCOTL GR</name> 
     <board> London</board> 
     <industry> Unknown</industry> 
     <prevPrice> 23.74</prevPrice> 
     <openPrice> 23.41</openPrice> 
     <lastPrice> 24.4</lastPrice> 
     <highPrice> 24.855</highPrice> 
     <lowPrice> 23.0</lowPrice> 
     <volume> 51353968</volume> 
     <changePrice> 0.66</changePrice> 
     <changePricePercentage> 2.78</changePricePercentage> 
     <lastVolume> 795</lastVolume> 
     <buyPrice> 24.39</buyPrice> 
     <buyQuantity> 51203</buyQuantity> 
     <sellPrice> 24.4</sellPrice> 
     <sellQuantity> 370763</sellQuantity> 
     <secondBuyPrice> 0.0</secondBuyPrice> 
     <secondBuyQuantity> 0</secondBuyQuantity> 
     <secondSellPrice> 0.0</secondSellPrice> 
     <secondSellQuantity> 0</secondSellQuantity> 
     <thirdBuyPrice> 0.0</thirdBuyPrice> 
     <thirdBuyQuantity> 0</thirdBuyQuantity> 
     <thirdSellPrice> 0.0</thirdSellPrice> 
     <thirdSellQuantity> 0</thirdSellQuantity> 
     <calendar> 
       <time> 1319038099446</time> 
       <timezone> America/New_York</timezone> 
     </calendar> 
   </org.yccheok.jstock.engine.Stock>
</java.util.Collections>
```

I am trying to extract the tag values of the code inner tag and changePricePercentage in C#. I am also trying to pre-populate a DataTable with these values. How do I handle the inner tag of code as well? Even though I am no expert, here is my C# source code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;

namespace XMLParser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("code", typeof(string)); ;
            table.Columns.Add("changePricePercentage", typeof(double));
            // Create a new XmlDocument  
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            // Load data  
            doc.Load(@"C:\...\realtimestock.xml");

            // Set up namespace manager for XPath  

            // Get forecast with XPath  
            //XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("org.yccheok.jstock.engine.Stock", ns);
            XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("org.yccheok.jstock.engine.Stock");
            // You can also get elements based on their tag name and namespace,  
            // though this isn't recommended  
            //XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("org.yccheok.jstock.engine.Stock");
            //                          "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");  

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}F - {3}F",
                //                     node.Attributes["code"].InnerText,
                //                     node.Attributes["changePricePercentage"].InnerText);

                Console.WriteLine("1: {0} 2: {1}", node.Attributes["code"].InnerText,
node.Attributes["changePricePercentage"].InnerText);

                table.Rows.Add(node.Attributes["code"].InnerText, node.Attributes["changePricePercentage"].InnerText);

                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I get my code to accomplish this task? 
P.S. This Stackoverflow editor would not accept my XML code properly so I had to edit with the actual symbol names. Sorry 
Thanks

Comment: Where's the XML structure? :-S

Comment: It is messy but I am not using an XSL but it is sandwhiched between the 'lessthan' and 'greaterthan' block. This StackExchange editor would not accept the raw XML code block where it complained about the formatting. I did even the formatting the expected so my apologies there.

Comment: @heavyrockerdude, you just need to put four spaces before every line and you're good to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//org.yccheok.jstock.engine.Stock");

foreach (XmlElement element in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1: {0} 2: {1}", 
        element.SelectSingleNode("code").InnerText,
        element.SelectSingleNode("changePricePercentage").InnerText);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Your `code` and `changePricePercentage` nodes are elements, not attributes, that was your mistake.

Comment: Wow!! This is awesome. Thanks so Rubens. Next question is how do I sort the default table? I tried:             table.DefaultView.Sort = "[" + table.Columns[1].ColumnName + "] asc";

Comment: For a new question, create a new question =)